# Retrieving Required SQL Parameters from a String in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

We're creating an app that would allow for a user to run official SQL queries for pre-defined tasks and reporting.

What we're trying to accomplish essentially is the same functionality that's in Query Designer of SSRS when you're trying to edit your query in the Dataset Properties pane. So for example, if I use a query type of Text and use something like the following SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM PersonsTable
WHERE LastName = @lastNameParam
```

The Query Parameter window will pop-up and ask the user to populate a value for that parameter:

[image: Query Parameter Prompt]

Is the source code / disassembly of this particular logic available somewhere that we can reference? If not, does anyone have recommendations on how we can mimic this behavior? Ideally it will allow us to accept SQL scripts that have DECLARE statements in them which seems like a limitation in what SSRS offers, but we're willing to settle if that's something we'd have to strip for the logic to fully work. Our initial attempts involved RegEx which didn't work so well, and the next we're considering is having to convert the scripts into temp stored procs and just use the built-in SQL logic to read the parameters, but feels a little overkill for the task.

Note that there's a separate workstream for the security aspect of this, so rest assured there will be processes for the execution, audit, and likewise implementation of security measures in code that we'll be taking into account as well once we can get the main functionality working. The official scripts are vetted through multiple groups as-is, and are version-controlled already. I hope that alleviates any potential concern with that aspect as inputs are brought forward to this thread.

Comment: _for a user to run official SQL queries for **pre-defined** tasks and reporting_ - if you have predefined tasks - than maybe you can have a collection with predefined sql queries and associated with it parameters - If you do that than you don't need to implement "sql parser", but user can select a query and pass required or optional parameters to it

Comment: I second what @Fabio said. This would be by far the easiest and most reasonable approach (and arguably the safest, because you wouldn't have to worry about patching someone's attempts to drop a table and what not, just sanitize your input and Bob's your auntie :P).

Comment: I certainly agree with the points provided. However, we have several instances of the system that we support, each instance can utilize the same pre-defined tasks, but the corresponding queries can require more or fewer parameters depending on the instance where it's being run. We're hoping to avoid having to put that mapping into code or some text file to tell the code which parameters to show up for each and every file.

Comment: Not looked into this but looks quite comprehensive , might be worth a look  http://www.sqlparser.com/

Comment: @robertviper08 Not sure I follow exactly, maybe a few examples would clarify what you mean on your last comment. But if you have multiple instances you have to support, your mapping would probably be best managed in a database Table itself. I'm not sure if you'd need a mapping any more or less though when your queries allow any combination of the parameters, if they don't then even with your parser goal you'd still need a way to manage that.

Comment: If you going to provide user functionality similar to "Query builder" then give those user required access to database and they can do it via SSRS ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is a `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSqlParser` type (with concrete subtypes like `TSql150Parser`) in the [`ScriptDom` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom/), that can be used to analyze and understand TSQL scripts as syntax trees. From there, you can determine the required parameters. It is a little laborious - and you'd probably need to write a visitor (subclassing `TSqlConcreteFragmentVisitor`) to determine when local variables are declared *inside* the TSQL (to exclude them), but yes: it can be done. We have code that does this as a Roslyn analyzer to check that we've included all the required parameters in Dapper invocations :)

Our visitor is below; after calling:

```
using var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(sqlString);
var fragment = sqlParser.Parse(stringReader, out var errors);
// TODO: report errors
var variablesVisitor = new TSqlVariablesVisitor();
fragment.Accept(variablesVisitor);
```

the parameters you need to define should be in `variablesVisitor.UnknownVariables`.

```
    private class TSqlVariablesVisitor : TSqlConcreteFragmentVisitor
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> UnknownVariables => _unknownVariables.AsEnumerable();
        private readonly HashSet<string> _unknownVariables = new HashSet<string>();
        private readonly HashSet<string> _knownVariables = new HashSet<string>();

        // we need to keep track of all the declared variables, we don't need to check those...
        private void OnVariableDeclaration(string variableName)
        {
            if (!_unknownVariables.Contains(variableName))
            {
                _knownVariables.Add(variableName);
            }
        }

        public override void Visit (DeclareVariableElement node)
        {
            OnVariableDeclaration(node.VariableName.Value);
            base.Visit(node);
        }

        public override void Visit (DeclareTableVariableBody node)
        {
            OnVariableDeclaration(node.VariableName.Value);
            base.Visit(node);
        }

        public override void Visit (VariableReference node)
        {
            if (!_knownVariables.Contains(node.Name))
            {
                _unknownVariables.Add(node.Name);
            }
            base.Visit(node);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We've ended up with utilizing RegEx.

\B@\w+\b(?!\s*=)(?!\s*(?i)TABLE(?i))

^ Grabs all variables names used within the script.

(\B@\w+\b(?=\s*(?i) AS (?i).+=)|((?<!(?i)WHEN(?i)\s*)\B\B@\w+\b(?=\s*=)))

^ Grabs all variables whose values have been set.

Then reconciling between the two lists created from the result to exclude all variables already set from being prompted to the user. There's still some fine-tuning involved and will require a couple more tests, but so far it's prompting the right set of variables that really requires an input from the user.

Thanks for the responses.